# Asp.net playing sounds in sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio

I have a webpage and based on the values on the page, when it loads, I need it to play up to 3 sounds. One after the other.

I have tried SoundManager2 but the onfinish method does not work in IE11.

I do not need to display any controls, it must simply play the sounds, in sequence and they are 3 different files which cannot be joined into one file.

What other way are there to play sounds where you can specify to play another sound after the first one has stopped playing?

Comment: At the bottom of this post there are five or six links to javascript audio player which might help http://patorjk.com/blog/2012/07/22/tone-playing-experiment-with-html5s-web-audio-api/